This token is not on the default token lists
I've been adding liquidity to my token on Raydium but I keep encountering a warning that says,
"This token is not on the default token lists."
I would like to understand what steps are necessary to get my token included on these default token lists to avoid this warning in the future.
Could someone guide me on the process or direct me to the relevant resources?
